# Generation of completely uniformly distributed sequences

Tags: quasi-monte-carlo

In quasi-Monte Carlo, there is a rather strong notion "completely uniformly distributed" sequences, which somehow mimics independence and is described, for example, at the end of [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40419/222528).

While the theory is clear to me, how do we practically generate such sequences? I can't find a reference, but I think I've heard that we can construct such a sequence from a low-discrepancy sequence (like a Sobol sequence) by random permutation of the indices?

Does anybody have a reference at hand or can briefly describe an easy-to-implement method to produce them?

*EDIT*: I know that there is the [paper of Levin](https://u.cs.biu.ac.il/%7Emlevin/Levin%201999%20Intern%20Math%20Resh%20Notes.pdf), but the construction described is rather complex. Especially in high dimension (I'm interested in a dimension around 40 at least), this seems to be hard to implement.

Comment: The post you link to answers your question.  It gives at least six different ways!

Comment: @whuber Huh? No, it does *not*. It shows different ways to construct uniformly distributed sequences; not *completely* uniformly distributed sequences!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!  I had not noticed the distinction.

Comment: @whuber No surprise, the terminology is miserable (if you ask me).